# json_decode deserialization error with curl

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, encode

I've created a Rest API that is working well, but I noticed a strange thing. For deserializing the content sent by the client I use this code:

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));
```

If I send a request with `POSTMAN` (Chrome Extension), all is working well, see:

[image]

but if I use `curl` with `MINGW64`, I'll get `NULL`:

[image]

Now in both cases, I checked the encoding type which was with this code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$encode =  mb_detect_encoding($content, "auto");
$json = mb_convert_encoding($content, $encode);
var_dump($json);
```

and this returns `UTF-8`

I don't understand why, with curl `MINGW64`, the console is not working, yet with the extension, or is working. What's happeni.g?

**UPDATE**

I've executed this function: `json_last_error()`, and it returned `5`. On this [site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), I saw that the number corresponds to an error:

```
5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8
```

But I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: You can try read content from file, to be sure console did not corrupt encoding.

Comment: @vitas what do you mean from file?

Comment: `curl -i -H "token: Company" -X PUT http://localhost/...   --data-binary @input.json` and in file `input.json` will be your JSON request.

Comment: @vitas uhm I don't like this solution, I want use the `-d`, but not working with console..

Comment: But it helps you determine, where problem is. My guess is your console is not UTF8. Try `echo Questo è test|xxd`. If correct UTF8 result is: `
00000000: 5175 6573 746f 20c3 a820 7465 7374 0a    Questo .. test.` (`è` is encoded by 2 bytes)

Comment: @vitas with your hint in console I get: `Questo ├¿ test`. I noticed that with my c# program and with chrome extension using this code: `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)` all working good. The problem is only on the `MINGW64` console. But I don't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are submitting JSON data in the body, you need to tell the server the content-type, otherwise cURL is sending it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Additionally, any UTF-8 characters need to be encoded in `\uXXXX` format to have a valid JSON string.

Try:

```
curl -i -H "token: company" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d '{"Code": "R89d", "Descri": "Questo \u00E8 un test"}' \
-X PUT http://localhost/api/customer/add
```

Edit:

Not sure what you're starting out with, but you can use the following two commands to supply cURL with a proper JSON string.

```
var=$(php -r 'echo json_encode(["Code" => "R89d", "Descri" => "Questo è un test"]);')
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "$var" http://sandbox/test.php
```

Comment: Well, if I use this:  `curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Code": "R89d", "Descri": "Test"}' -X PUT http://localhost/apicustomer/add` working well. But if I add accented letters like this: `curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Code": "R89d", "Descri": "Questo è un test"}' -X PUT http://localhost/apicustomer/add` the function `json_decode` return `NULL`. This situation happean only with the console, with my desktop application or Postman all working good.

Comment: That's because the JSON string needs to be properly escaped.  What you are sending is invalid JSON.  It needs to look like: `{"Code": "R89d", "Descri": "Questo \u00E8 un test"}`

Comment: you're right, seems working now. But I can't think that things are so complex for `curl` requests. There would be a way to handle this via code or something? Otherwise I should remember the encoding for accented letters, or convert the string with some tools... after some time use of `curl` can become tedious and frustrating. What do you suggest me?

Comment: When you pass raw data like that to cURL, it is not its job to encode it.  It doesn't know if you're posting binary application data, JSON, XML, application/x-www-url-encoded data or something else, so it does not change your input.  In the case of sending JSON, you need to supply cURL with valid JSON.  I'm not sure of any standard command line utilities to unicode escape a JSON string, but see my edit showing how to use PHP to json_encode a value, and then use the return data to pass to curl.

Answer (score 0):

Converting encoding to utf-8 worked for me.
`$retorno_transaction = mb_convert_encoding($retorno_transaction, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Thank you for your insight and solution. If you know how or why this fixes the issue, consider an `edit` to share the reasoning with others to improve quality of your answer, increase upvotes, & spread deeper understanding of the ecosystem with other devs. Documentation links can also be helpful for some answers. If unknown, that's ok too - it can still help others, & perhaps even prompt someone else to shed light on your solution. Cheers.